# logic needed to post the data using if condition in node js (validation needed)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

This is my existing schema,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const position = mongoose.Schema({
    startIndex: { type: Number, required: true },
    endIndex: { type: Number, required: false },
}); 

const Column = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    type: { type: String, enum: ["Description","ID","Time"], required: true },
    positions: [position],
    dataType: { type: String, enum: ["int", "float", "Double","String"], required: true },
    oldName: {type:String, required: false }
});

const enrichedEventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    projectId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Project', required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true,unique: true },
    DataSourceID: { type: String, required: false},
    delimiter: { type: String, required: true },
    format: {type:String, enum:["JSON","DELIMITED","FixedWidth","LOG"], required: true},
    columns:[Column]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('EnrichedEvent', enrichedEventSchema);


Api for Post route:

router.post("/:projectId/events/enriched", (req, res, next) => {
    const enrichedEvent = new EnrichedEvent({
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: req.body.name,
        projectId: req.params.projectId, //taking from url
        delimiter: req.body.delimiter,
        format: req.body.format,
        columns:req.body.columns,
     });

    return enrichedEvent.save()
        .then(result => {
            res.status(201).json({
                message: "Event stored",
                createdEvent: {
                    _id: result._id,
                    projectId: result.projectId,
                    name: result.name,
                    type: result.type,
                    delimiter: result.delimiter,
                    columns:result.columns,
                    format:result.format
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });
        });
});
```

well my requirement is that 
All EnrichedEvents Should have at least 2 Columns defined one with

Type = ID,
    Type = TIME.

```
if FORMAT = DELIMITED  then data must have Delimiter Field; ALL Columns should have a mandatory Starting Index. 
if FORMAT = FIXEDWIDTH  then data must have all Columns should have mandatory Starting and Ending Index.
```

all i could come up with is using if condition, something like this.

```
 if ( req.body.format == 'DELIMITED' )
 {
//then how to use my schema in my code??
 }
```

I m stuck in this for 3 days, not getting logic. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try making two different schemes.

```
const positionDel = mongoose.Schema({
    startIndex: { type: Number, required: true },
    endIndex: { type: Number, required: false },
}); 
const positionFixed = mongoose.Schema({
    startIndex: { type: Number, required: true },
    endIndex: { type: Number, required: true},
});
```

Comment: Its not working, can i know where should i include if condition?

Comment: make sure you are using body-parser module for node.

Comment: using body-parser module since the beginning of the project

Answer (score 0):

```
router.post("/:projectId/events/enriched", (req, res, next) => {
    const enrichedEvent = new EnrichedEvent({
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: req.body.name,
        projectId: req.params.projectId, //taking from url
        delimiter: req.body.delimiter,
        format: req.body.format,
        columns:req.body.columns,
     });

     if(delimiter=='DELIMITED'){
        return enrichedEvent_SchemaForDELIMITED.save()
        .then(result=>{
            //use the result.
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            // error thrown
        })
     }
     else if(delimiter=="FIXEDWIDTH"){
        return enrichedEvent_SchemaForFIXED.save()
        .then(result=>{
            //use the result.
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            // error thrown
        })
     }

});
```

Look at the code. The logic will be like this.

Comment: I m editing the code for according to my needs, ll check it in few minutes